# UI Bug when cancelling a comment edit on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, user-interface, mobile-web

On my HTC desire at least;

1. Add a comment to a post
2. Click the edit button for that comment
3. Cancel your edit

The comment gets displaced to the right of the original comment stream, and ends up looking [*something* like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PmVt.jpg) (warning; awsm paint skills are included in the previous link);

[image: awsm paint skills]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great red marker sample image, but it doesn't seem to happen anymore. Not that looking at this 2.5 years later helps...

Comment: I don't even have that phone any more to check... but I'll take your word for it ;).